# How to calculate Total working hours of employee by each session

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display employee login and logout hours for each session of the day and calculate Total Working hours. If the employee login and logout many times, each session and total should be displayed.

My table will be look like this

| Id | EmpId | LocationId | LogDate | AccessType | OutType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 16:27:41.217 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 17:27:26.673 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 17:31:30.333 | 1 | NULL |
| 5 | 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 19:31:38.973 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 1212_8 | 1212 | 2022-05-26 10:21:38.973 | 1 | NULL |
| 6 | 1212_8 | 1212 | 2022-05-26 12:21:38.973 | 2 | 2 |

Here
AccessType 1=IN 2=OUT
OutType  1=LogOut 2=Session Out

I want the output like this

| EmpId | LocationId | SessionStart | SessionEnd | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 16:27:41.217 | 2022-05-25 17:27:26.673 | 1:00 |
| 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 17:31:30.333 | 2022-05-25 19:31:38.973 | 2:00 |
| 1212_8 | 1212 | 2022-05-26 10:21:38.973 | 2022-05-26 12:21:38.973 | 2:00 |

This is what I tried

```
select[EmpId],
[LocationId],
ShiftDate, 
SessionStartTime, 
SessionEndTime
, Total_Time = right(concat('0', Total_Time / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', Total_Time % 3600 / 60), 2)  
from (
    select
       [EmpId],[LocationId], ShiftDate = cast(min(LogDate) as date)
        , SessionStartTime = min(LogDate)
        , SessionEndTime = max(LogDate)
        , Total_Time = sum(ss)
      
    from (
        select
            *, ss = datediff(ss, LogDate, lead(LogDate) over (partition by [EmpId], grp order by LogDate))
        from (
            select
                *, grp = sum(diff) over (partition by [EmpId] order by LogDate)
            from (
                select
                    *, diff = iif(datediff(mi, lag(LogDate) over (partition by [EmpId] order by LogDate), LogDate) > 300 and [AccessType] = 1, 1, 0)
                from
                    [tblEmployeeAttendance]  where cast(LogDate as date) >= '2022-05-25'  and cast(LogDate as date) <= '2022-05-26'
            ) t
        ) t
    ) t 
    group by [EmpId],[LocationId], grp) t
```

I got result like this

| EmpId | LocationId | SessionStart | SessionEnd | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 16:27:41.217 | 2022-05-25 19:31:38.973 | 3:00 |
| 1212_8 | 1212 | 2022-05-26 10:21:38.973 | 2022-05-26 12:21:38.973 | 2:00 |

Here the problem is I get only min login and max logout for the day in one row. But I need each login and logout session of the user on the day and total for each.

I request somebody to help on this.

Comment: Its not OK to say things that imply a priority, urgency, time factor etc (as you originally said "Its very critical"). The better quality the question the more likely you'll get a good answer in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an outer apply.
I don't know what the OutType is used for, what the difference is with AccessType. You did not explain that or any other logic so I just assumed it should work on AccessType.
If that is not the case you can easy adapt the logic in the subquery below.

```
select e.EmpId,
       e.LocationID,
       e.logdate as SessionStart,
       d.logdate as SessionEnd,
       datediff(hour, e.logdate, d.logdate) as Hours
from   emp e
  outer apply ( select top 1 emp.logdate
                from   emp
                where  emp.empid = e.empid
                and    emp.accesstype = 2
                and    emp.logdate > e.logdate
                order by emp.logdate
              ) d
where  e.accesstype = 1
```

See the [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd0b187724cf47461a2ab439961be44e) here

Result

| EmpId | LocationID | SessionStart | SessionEnd | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 16:27:41.217 | 2022-05-25 17:27:26.673 | 1 |
| 4545_1 | 4545 | 2022-05-25 17:31:30.333 | 2022-05-25 19:31:38.973 | 2 |
| 1212_8 | 1212 | 2022-05-26 10:21:38.973 | 2022-05-26 12:21:38.973 | 2 |